# Python - string checks and replacement for similar word

Tags: python, string

I have 3 strings:

```
string1 = 'HTGS_PHASE2 "HTGS_PHASE0"'
string2 = 'HTG'
string3 = 'HTGS_PHASE0'
```

I have tried the following:

```
string1 = 'HTGS_PHASE2 "HTGS_PHASE0"'
string2 = 'HTG'
string3 = 'HTGS_PHASE2'

if string3 in string1:
    newstring = string1.replace(string3,'')
print(newstring)
```

Will give me the expected output:

```
"HTGS_PHASE0"
```

However, I wish to make it such that:

```
if string2 in string1:
    #nothing should happen here. replacement should not happen.
    newstring = string1.replace(string2,'')
```

However, string2 will always be detected as being a substring of string1.
As a result, this output is given:

```
S_PHASE2 "S_PHASE0"
```

How do I make it such that the second scenario is not possible?

**EDIT: I would also preferably not use strip(), as the string in " " or the other side of the space in string1 is allowed to contain spaces as well.**

Comment: You could try using regex. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: What exactly is the criteria for saying yes or no? How about "HTGS" or "PHASE2" or "GS_PHASE0" or "htgs_phase0"?

Comment: @GinoMempin I have rephrased my question

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`fuzzywuzzy`](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) package. Depending on the criteria for matching, you can use the various modules available in the package. I would recommend looking through a tutorial on the package (try [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/string-matching-with-fuzzywuzzy-e982c61f8a84)), but to me, this seems like your best function choice:

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

match_string = "HTGS_PHASE2 'HTGS_PHASE0'"
options = ['HTG', 'HTGS_PHASE0']

process.extract(match_string, choices, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking how to add some additional logic other than "is this string a subset of this other string", which is what the python `in` operator checks for.

More specifically, it sounds like what you are asking is "How to match a substring `HTG`, only when it is a standalone word in the larger string.

Specifically what makes something a standalone word is the logic you would like to add.

One way of doing this might be to check for the string `'HTG '` rather than `'HTG'` but this approach gets complex if you want to also match anything more complex.

A useful tool for complex substring logic is [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) or regex. The python standard library has a useful [regex module](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Some examples of how to use:

```py
    >>> p = re.compile(r'\bHTG\b')
    >>> p.sub('','HTG_PHASE2 "HTGS_PHASE0"')
    'HTG_PHASE2 "HTGS_PHASE0"'
    >>> p.sub('','HTG')
    ''
    >>> p.sub('','HTG_PHASE2')
    'HTG_PHASE2'
    >>> p.sub('','HTG_PHASE2 HTG')
    'HTG_PHASE2 '
```

note that in the above example, the additional word boundary logic is added with the regex `\b` token, which represents a word boundary.

From the [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re-syntax):

> A word is defined as a sequence of word characters. Note that
> formally, `\b` is defined as the boundary between a `\w` and a `\W`
> character (or vice versa), or between `\w` and the beginning/end of the
> string. This means that `r'\bfoo\b'` matches `'foo'`, `'foo.'`, `'(foo)'`,
> `'bar foo baz'` but not `'foobar'` or `'foo3'`.